# Sampling in Text Classification: can the results be considered 'reliable'?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, sampling, confusion-matrix, text-classification

I am testing different models (SVM, Logistic Regression, Naive Bayes, Random Forest) for predicting the class of a spam email. My target is a binary variable.
I am analysing only text, no other fields.
My dataset includes

```
Label  
0.0    3333
1.0     768
```

As you can see there is a big problem with classes imbalanced.
I read about the use of downsampling and upsampling, so I applied them before training and testing the dataset.
I got good results in terms of F1, recall and accuracy for upsampling (above 88%; max 97%), bad for downsampling (<=76%).
For instance:

```
Down
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.79      0.43      0.56       102
         1.0       0.61      0.87      0.76       114


Confusion Matrix: 
 [[ 49  60]
 [ 12 100]]


Up
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       1.00      0.85      0.91       873
         1.0       0.87      1.00      0.94       884



Confusion Matrix: 
 [[772 141]
 [  20 822]]
```

I would like to ask you if these values can be considered good results or they can't. I am considering  a publication (not only to include similar analysis), so I would like to check if such results can be considered reliable, despite of the imbalance.

Any suggestions and advice will be greatly welcome.

Comment: Refer this Workflow: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a mistake in your method:

> I read about the use of downsampling and upsampling, so I applied them before training and testing the dataset.

It's incorrect to change the distribution of the test set. When resampling, the resampling should be applied only on the training set. The goal is to force the model to take into account the two classes, because in case of imbalance the model tends to focus on the majority class. However the true proportion of the class in the "real dataset" is still the same, and the test set should follow this true proportion. Otherwise the performance looks artificially good on the test set, even though the classifier will make more mistakes with real data since it doesn't have the same distribution.

So the performance values that you obtain on a resampled dataset are meaningless, I'm afraid.

> I am considering a publication (not only to include similar analysis), so I would like to check if such results can be considered reliable, despite of the imbalance.

If you are considering a peer-reviewed publication, you must also make sure that your contribution is original (i.e. new) and brings some advantage over the existing methods. This means that you need to know the state of the art in spam classification (there are [a lot of papers already published about this task](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=survey%20email%20spam%20detection%20OR%20filtering)) and show what your method improves something compared to the existing methods. Ideally this is done by proving that your new method obtains better performance than the state of the arts methods using a benchmark dataset. But it's usually hard to beat state of the art performance on a well-known problem.

Comment: Thanks so for your answer, Erwan. I think there has been a misunderstanding (maybe) on applying the up/downsampling in the training dataset. What I have done has been to create two subsets, one for spam and one for not spam from my original dataset. After that I applied the upsampling and downsampling. It should be right, should it not? Regarding the publication, you are right and I will follow your advice. Since I think you have more experience than me (I am at the first year of PhD), I would like to ask you if you think that adding more features in the analysis (num of words, email address,

Comment: punctuation, upper case words, and others) might be considered worthy to be published. There is a lot of papers as you said that is difficult to find an algorithm that can be improved results of 99.7%. I am getting for downsampled dataset values around 76%, while for upsampling values around 97%. On arXiv there are so many papers, even uploaded in November 2020 that 'repeat' the same story ...

Comment: But did your two subsets come from the same source? The standard process would be to collect a large number of emails from diverse sources over a given period of time, then label them as either spam or not. This way the proportion of spam in the dataset is roughly the same as what what it would be in real conditions, when the spam filter is applied to all the incoming email. If the two subsets don't come from the same source, for example if they were collected separately, then the dataset is biased from the start. Of course you can play with it for testing/educational purposes, but it ...

Comment: wouldn't be considered a reliable dataset. Is this work part of your PhD? Is your topic about NLP or similar? It's normal to spend some time in the first year discovering problems and methods so it's fine, but if this your main PhD work I hope that you're aware that it's a field which progresses very fast (I can't keep track myself ;) ), nowadays it's very likely that the state of the art in spam filtering requires more advanced methods like Deep Learning. I don't know the context of your work but in general there's little chance to outperform the state of the art with standard methods on ...

Comment: ... this kind of problem. Obviously I don't know anything about your work so take this with a grain of salt, but I'd suggest you make sure (typically with your supervisor) that your PhD direction/topic is original enough to lead to publishing material. For example ideas such as resampling, feature engineering with punctuation/case are very standard techniques which have probably been tried before, so I doubt it's going to be enough to publish in a decent conference/journal.

Comment: Note that you could probably find other datasets for the task for example from [the TREC shared tasks](https://trec.nist.gov/data/spam.html). There might be other more recent available datasets as well, these would certainly be mentioned in the publications about the task.

Comment: Hi Erwan, thanks you so much for all your precious and kind advise. My work is about spam and fakeness and yes, I am aware that these are fields which progresses very fast.   I am trying to look at all possible material and newest articles/papers on spam/fake news but most of the works are repeating the same things and procedures in a very standard way (including myself). my main source is arXiv, but I have not found a lot of material new, standard techniques and, sometimes, new approaches. A lot of benchmarking documentation... I do not know if changing source of data maybe also good for

Comment: applying similar techniques but on a dataset that was built from scratch (maybe not in case of spam emails, but more on fake news). It was very nice to have a chat with you. I think I have learnt a lot having this chat with you :)  (unfortunately I have had not the same 'fortune' with my tutor as I am working almost alone on my Phd project - and it is to easy, at all).

Comment: @Math I'm not surprised, I had a feeling that your are not very well supervised. I don't know your situation at all but if you want to maximize your chances to succeed the PhD you need advice from somebody who is expert in this field. Practically whether it's your supervisor or anybody else doesn't really matter, but officially it's your supervisor's responsibility. If things are really not satisfying on this side, you could consider talking to other people in your group, maybe even a meeting with whoever in your department is in charge of PhD students. If there is a serious lack of ...

Comment: ... supervision, it's important to address the issue as soon as possible because you don't want to spend too much PhD time working in a "wrong" direction ("wrong" = not sure to lead to publications and PhD degree). Sometimes a department head can help finding a co-supervisor who is expert in the domain. Be aware that I'm just giving you random advice here as I don't know your situation, also this site is not meant for this kind of advice anyway :) Btw there's [AcademiaSE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) for questions about academia. So use your best judgement, and good luck for the PhD :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the good advice, Erwan. I will have a look at AcademiaSE, I did not know about this section, so thanks a lot also for letting me know about that :)